# Unable to push a figure to the top of an empty page

Tags: floats, positioning

I am writing a thesis and I have a figure which appears near the end of a chapter. It happens that there is no sufficient space for it at the last page so it is floated to the next new empty page. And it appears in the middle. I want it to appear at the top of the empty page.

I have spent a lot of time trying different combinations of the figure optional arguments "t", "!", "h" and "p". I also tried to use \phantom{\blindtext} trying to use some invisible text to push the figure up. Both approaches do not work for me. The only way is to write some visible garbage texts at the end of the figure, then it will be pushed up to the top; but of course I don't want garbage texts to appear in my thesis.

I read through some answers on similar questions but I don't want to change the margin and format of the thesis. That will make this figure inconsistent with the other figures in my thesis.

This is the last paragraph and the figure I have:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
                \begin{center}
               \includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{pic/Pic1}
               \caption{Pic1}
               \label{fig:pic1}
            \end{center}
       \end{subfigure}%
       \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
               \includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{pic/Pic2}
               \caption{Pic2}
               \label{fig:pic2}
               \end{center}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{Pictures}\label{fig:pictures} \end{figure}


blah blah blah blah blah Figure~\ref{fig:pic1) blah blah blah blah Figure~\ref{fig:pic2}.
```

Comment: a trick :make your figure the last thing in the chapter and just before it use\newpage

Comment: don't use `[!t]` that prevents float pages and so just increases the chance of the figure going to the end of the chapter, you do not need an optional argument at all.